# How to calculate the suface area of a minimal surface?

Tags: calculus, minimal-surfaces, implicit-function

I have had a very interesting journey exploring minimal surfaces on the internet and I was wondering if there was a way to find the approximate surface area of a minimal surface that is represented by an implicit function. For example, is there a way to find the area of a gyroid from the equation $\sin (x)$$\cos (y)$ $+$ $\sin (y)$$\cos (z)$ $+$ $\sin (z)$$\cos (x)$ $=$ 0 over defined bounds $x$, $y$, and $z$?